# Has anyone in sports returned from a grade 3 ankle sprain in one month?

Tags: basketball, injuries

Sabrina Ionescu plans to come back from her grade 3 ankle sprain in one month, in time for the WNBA playoffs. She plans to **conquer rehab**. I've read it takes longer than a month to heal from a grade 3 ankle sprain.

Has anyone in sports returned from a grade 3 sprain in one month?